# Monotouch capabilities

Tags: iphone, ipad, xamarin.ios

I am a C# developer who is going to start the development of an iPhone/iPad Application.

My question is very simple: with monotouch, can I do all I can do with standard objectC?

Comment: No, you can't since ObjC and C are what the native OS API are, but you can do pretty much everything you might want to.

Comment: I used C# extensively before learning Objective-C. It's really a very easy language transition. In my opinion you're much better off spending a day or two learning Objective-C as there is so much more sample code written for it. And, either way you will have to learn the design patterns behind Cocoa. Also, it's substantially easier to navigate the documentation if you're using Objective-C, and I'm sure plenty of iOS developers will agree; The easier it is for you to use the documentation the easier your life will be ten fold. I can recommend a few books if you would like?

Comment: Jason Coco is just plain wrong. The fact the ObjC is native has nothing to do with what you can and what you can't do with MonoTouch. MonoTouch also compiles to "native" code for the iPhone, and can call all the APIs available in ObjC. Heck, you can even write libraries in C/ObjC if you want and call those from your MonoTouch project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty much, yes.  Monotouch updates come out very rapidly after iOS updates, so you have access to new APIs almost immediately.

You can still use third-part objective-c libraries, too: http://monotouch.net/Features#Access_to_third_party_iPhone.2fObjective-C_Libraries

Clearly, this implies that you can still use objective-c in a Monotouch app if you ever find it necessary.

Comment: This is correct. I have written a C library to interface with hardware, that gets called from MonoTouch.